# Not able to track and get values of MAPI properties of a message .msg file using Aapche_poi_3.10 API

Tags: java, email, apache-poi, msg

I'm facing difficulty in reading some MAPI property of a .msg file using Apache POI 3.10 jar file.

The code is written below.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.poi.hsmf.MAPIMessage;
import org.apache.poi.hsmf.datatypes.AttachmentChunks;

public class MessageReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream  file = new FileInputStream("C:\\testMail_1.msg");

        MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage(file);

        HashMap  msg_aspect = new HashMap();

        msg_aspect.put("attachment_count",msg.getAttachmentFiles().length);

        msg_aspect.put("from_addr", msg.getDisplayFrom());

        msg_aspect.put("i_partition", 0);

        msg_aspect.put("is_signed", false);

        msg_aspect.put("message_class", msg.getMessageClass() );

        msg_aspect.put("message_subject",msg.getSubject());

        msg_aspect.put("receive_date", msg.getMessageDate().getTime());

        msg_aspect.put("send_date", msg.getMessageDate().getTime());

        ArrayList attchChk = new ArrayList();

        for(AttachmentChunks atchChk :msg.getAttachmentFiles()){

            String attachFileName = String.valueOf(((atchChk.attachLongFileName == null)?(atchChk.attachFileName+".msg"):atchChk.attachLongFileName));

            attchChk.add(attachFileName);

        }

        msg_aspect.put("attachment_names", attchChk);

        ArrayList toAddr = new ArrayList();

        for(String user: msg.getDisplayTo().split(";")){

            if(!user.trim().equals("")){

                toAddr.add(user.trim());

            }
        }
        msg_aspect.put("to_addr", attchChk);

        ArrayList ccAddr = new ArrayList();

        for (String user : msg.getDisplayCC().split(";")) {

            if(!user.trim().equals("")){

                ccAddr.add(user.trim());

            }

        }


        msg_aspect.put("cc_addr", ccAddr);
                  }catch (Exception e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
   }
}
```

I'm facing difficulty in reading following MAPI Property and MAPI Property values.

1. Message's partition - I'm not able to find out which MAPI attribute will tell me if message is partitioned or not.
2. Message signed - Not able to track MAPI Property that can tell message's signing status.
3. Message's sixe - Not able to track MAPI Property that can tell Message's size. Message's size visible in outlook message list window. I found that message size is different than .msg file size.
4. Message's Receive Date - Not able to track MAPI Property. It is different then message's send date. msg.getMessageDate() is returning is message send date. I found it is availabe in message header but message header is only available with received mails, not available for sent mails.
5. I want sender and receipent's details in following format, if the mail communication happened among users within same Exchange server or same domain.
   EX:"testUser1"
6. Even if the the email id is availabe for both sender and receipent (along with To and CC identification) that will also fine. I have tried msg.getRecipientEmailAddressList() to get receipent email address but in this case all To and CC recipient are combined together and our requirement is to store details of To and CC recipient differently.
7. I'm not able to fetch sender's email address.

Please help me which MAPI Property can be used to server purpose and how I can get values associated with the MAPI properties to server the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try fetching all the MAPI Properties, not just the ones with helper getters? eg with a call to [getProperties()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hsmf/datatypes/Chunks.html#getProperties())?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Yes I tried with 
Set<Map.Entry<MAPIProperty,List<PropertyValue>>> entry = msg.getMainChunks().getProperties().entrySet();

but still the specified properties are not visible in property list.

Comment: Some of them may end up on the recipient chunks - did you check the properties on there too?

Comment: It could be a bug, as reported here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57744
Fixed in apache poi 3.11